# UE4: How to plot points from a data table using a particle system

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

I have imported a csv file into unreal. And now have a data table. The data table has x,y,z coordinates. I want to make it so that a particle system reads the data and creates a sprite at a location for each row in the data table. I currently have a blueprint that spawns an emitter for each row. But this is very slow with larger data sets. And I would like to spawn these sprites within the particle subsystem.

I'm open to more optimized solutions then using a data table if it is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datatable use is fine, but a particle system isn't. If your dataset has a relatively small number of points, just plot boxes or points using a blueprint. If it's a larger dataset, you may want to shift into code (use C++ to write points to a Texture2D and blit that to the screen).

Comment: Do you know how I could blit the points to the screen?
I don't really have experience in using c++ with unreal.

Comment: This is a pretty complex topic and would require C++. Can you give more details about number of points to plot, frequency of update etc.?

Comment: Number of points would be 10's of thousands or more.
Update frequency is not a big issue.
I found this example:https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/blueprint-visual-scripting/63159-how-to-place-single-gpu-particles-at-specified-locations
This might be enough
I don't know how to set up the texture to show the vertices that I want.

Comment: That's enough points to warrant C++. Try this: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/475962/dynamic-texture-memcpy.html